# Como permitir a mi dominio que suba archivos gigantes?

Tags: php, laravel, dominio

Estoy trabajando en laravel 8, php 7.2, localmente me sube muy bien imagenes de más de 20MB.

Pero al momento que lo pasé a un dominio ya no me permite creo que más de 2MB.

Ya cambie esto:
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M

Se que no tendría que permitir archivos tan grandes, pero lo hago con el fin de probar.

Uso directadmin como panel, o hay que reiniciar algún servicio o algo?

Comment: También debes aumentar la memoria de procesamiento, esto por la variable `memory_limit`, este debe ser mayor que la de `post_max_size`, ya cambiando esto, debes reiniciar apache para que obtenga las nuevas configuraciones.

Comment: Después de modificar `php.ini` debes reiniciar el servicio de Apache para aplicar los cambios.